# list trigger no system ending with "_BI"

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I want to list the trigger no system ending with "_BI" in firebird database,
but no result with this

```
select * from  rdb$triggers
where 
rdb$trigger_source is not null 
and (coalesce(rdb$system_flag,0) = 0) 
and (rdb$trigger_source not  starting with 'CHECK' )
and (rdb$trigger_name like '%BI')
```

but with this syntaxs it gives me a "_bi" and "_BI0U" and "_BI0U" ending result

```
and (rdb$trigger_name like '%BI%')
```

but with this syntaxs it gives me null result
    and (rdb$trigger_name like '%@_BI')

thank you beforehand

Comment: Please improve your question. What do you mean with "false result", also does the first query work or not (the first sentence suggests it doesn't, but the second sentence suggests it does).

Comment: Also, what do you think `'%@_BI'` would do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Firebird system tables use `CHAR(31)` for object names, this means that they are padded with spaces up to the declared length. As a result, use of `like '%BI'`) will not yield results, unless BI are the 30th and 31st character.

There are several solutions

For example you can trim the name before checking

```
trim(rdb$trigger_name) like '%BI'
```

or you can require that the name is followed by at least one space

```
rdb$trigger_name || ' ' like '%BI %'
```

On a related note, if you want to check if your trigger name ends in `_BI`, then you should also include the underscore in your condition. And as an underscore in `like` is a single character matcher, you need to escape it:

```
trim(rdb$trigger_name) like '%\_BI' escape '\'
```

Alternatively you could also try to use a regular expressions, as you won't need to trim or otherwise mangle the lefthand side of the expression:

```
rdb$trigger_name similar to '%\_BI[[:SPACE:]]*' escape '\'
```

Comment: thank you yes its work with trim(rdb$trigger_name) like '%BI' and all examples